# How to use data from one hook to other hook in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my **vue.js** application I send request by **axios** package in `created()` hook. I add response to array called *coordinates*. I want to use that array outside of `created()` hook. For example in `mounted()` hook or in functions which we can set in `methods`.

Right now when I tried to use `self.coordinates` outside `created()` hook it return `undefined`. When I use `this.coordinates` it return just `[__ob__: Observer]`.
Whats wrong I did?

```
export default {
    name: "Map",
    data() {
        return {
            coordinates: [],
        }
    },
    created() {
        let self = this;
        axios.get('URL').then(function (response) {
            let coordinates = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                coordinates.push([response.data[i]["LATITUDE"], response.data[i]["LONGITUDE"]]);
            }
            self.coordinates = coordinates;
        });
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(self.coordinates); // undefined
        consol.log(this.coordinates);  // [__ob__: Observer]
    },
}
```

Comment: You are referring to "self.coordinates" in the mounted() method, yet "self" is not defined. So it will result in "undefined". "this.coordinates" is the actual data object in you vue stack. I would not use the "created()" method for this ajax call, I would move that ajax call into the mounted method to manipulate the mutation listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer "mounted" and move the logic into methods for reusability. The method can be kicked from anywhere afterwards. In the example below, I prefered kicking the method direcly. Watchers is another option.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dj79ux5t/2/

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            coordinates: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        let self = this;
        axios.get('https://api.weather.gov/').then(function (response) {
            self.coordinates = response.data;
            self.greet();
        });
    },
  methods: {
    greet: function () {
        console.warn(this.coordinates.status);
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of mounted , you should use watch . You call some link so it will take time to load that data , watch method will trigger when your data is updated ...

```
watch: {
    coordinates: {
      handler: function (updateVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(updateVal)
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
```